# Convert Byte[] To BCD to int

Tags: c#, arrays

I want put in `int` every component of `byte[]` without convert them:

I have :

```
byte[] byte = {0x16,0x12,0x34}
```

I want decompose it:

```
 int Size = byte[0];
 int Type = byte[1];
 int Ref = byte[2];
```

But with this code i have

> 'Size = 22' 'Type = 18' 'Ref = 52'

He convert Hex To Decimal but i want

> 'Size = 16' 'Type =12' 'Ref = 34'

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your number is a proper BCD (i.e. neither digit is `A`..`F`) you can do it like this:

```
int Size = 10 * (byte[0] / 16) + (byte[0] % 16);
```

The idea is to reinterpret the upper digit, which represents the number of sixteens in a hex number, as a number of tens in a decimal number.

For example, dividing `0x52` by `16` in integer produces `5`, while remainder with `16` produces `2`. Now you multiply `5` by ten and add back the `2` to get the decimal number 52.